# Default root password for Bitnami Dreamfactory Stack

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, root, bitnami

I was trying to use MySQL Workbench to view and alter my tables on MySQL. The default password for other tools like mamp, wamp and lamp are usually root. However I tried using that and my computers root passwords, but both don't work. Can some one tell me what it is?

Comment: Don't you have *special* characters in your password? Sometimes, on specific clients, [it can be a mess](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49977) (try to escape it by using "\" before special chars?)

Comment: This is wildly off-topic - It has nothing to do with coding!

Comment: @smonff I finally found out the password was actually the admin password for dreamfactory. @ user3791372, you are right this is off topic, but dream factory helps you build APIs so you can make REST requests to your backend while you're coding in what ever language you intend to use. I felt this would be useful to some programmers out there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined by the Help Center.

Comment: Hey @TylerH, DreamFactory is an open source REST API platform for mobile enterprise application developers and Bitnami is the easiest way to install DreamFactory. My question is directly involved in programming as DreamFactory is a programming tool. If you want to build an API for your mobile application but have never built one, this tool is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on this [link](https://bitnami.com/stack/dreamfactory/README.txt).

MariaDB admin user is called 'root', and its password is the same as the
DreamFactory administrative user password.